# Add Small Circle/Dot Wherever User Taps Inside of UIView (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview, drawing, touchesbegan

I'm trying to figure out how to add a small circle/dot on a UIView but only when the user taps inside of the UIView. The dot should be placed wherever the user taps. I, unfortunately have no idea how to do this.

Any examples with code are very helpful! I'm using Swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your **View Controller** you should first implement `touchesBegan` method which gives you an array of `UITouch` objects that you can work with. Then each `UITouch` object has `locationInView` property which gives you the `CGPoint` location of the touch. You can save those locations in an array (attribute of your **VC**). Or you can initialize your **dot** object right away in this method.

```
func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in touches{
        let location = (touch as! UITouch).locationInView(self.courtView)
        var dot = UIView(frame: CGRect(location.x, location.y, 10, 10))
        self.courtView.addSubview(dot) //add dot as subview to your main view
        }
    }
```

What you give as an argument to `locationInView` mainly depends on your view hierarchy, it may be `self`, `self.contentView` or `self.view`. Same applies to where you add your **dot** as a subview.

Comment: @AndyLebowitz please mark as answered if you find it helpful

Comment: I tried using that code and nothing happened. A little confused now on how to get it to work correctly

Comment: @AndyLebowitz do you understand what should happen there? You should adjust this piece of code to your view controller

Comment: When I use NSSet at the top it says that the method doesn't override anything from its superclass

Comment: @AndyLebowitz ignore "override"

Comment: so my view is called "courtView" and I inserted your code but changed content view to court view and when I click inside the view nothing appears so do I need to write a function calling a circle or something?

Comment: @AndyLebowitz you see, 'var dot = UIView(frame: CGRect(location.x, location.y, 10, 10))' this line is just an initialization of your **dot**, you should initialize it as you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101497/discussion-between-andy-lebowitz-and-tmac-balla).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help!